# Get father of a UINAvigationBar (or other components) from itself

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

HI! Is it possible to reach father of a UINavigationBar ?

I added a UINavigationBar to an hierarchy and it would be great reach its father directly from UINavigationBar. 
(I'm working on Customization... and i override drawRect method, i would manage behavior depend on navigationBar father type)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the superview of the bar?

```
UINavigationBar *bar = ...;
UIView *parent = bar.superview;
```

Should work fine. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Yes,  that's exactly what i'm looking for.
And with [bar.superview class] i can know the superview type.
Thank you